# How do I re-install Windows 7 after doing a full install of Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7

Although I have enjoyed Ubuntu, my partner and I share a computer and they would like Windows 7 back. The problem is that I did a full install of Ubuntu 12.04, and have no idea how to get Windows 7 back on and I really don't want to mess up the computer.

I would need to boot from a USB.

Comment: You have erase the disk, that is what are you saying. So you will need to delete the partition, format it and install Windows 7. There is a post to know how to do it: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/62483)

Comment: Are you trying to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back? Or do you want to install Windows but also keep Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you install Ubuntu it installs itself over a 'boot loader' like [Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

With boot loader, you can get back to windows by selecting right option at startup(boot).

If in your case you don't have any boot loader installed and you had reformatted the windows partition, you have to install 'Windows 7' from starting.

To create a bootable USB in Ubuntu, see this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick